# Determinate where fetchEvent came from

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm using service worker and listening for any network request that are being made...

I would like to know if the request came from `<img>` or `<script>` would that be possible somehow?

**sw.js**

```
self.onfetch = event => {
    console.log(event)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have access to the [`Request` object](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request-class) that triggered your [`fetch` event](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#fetchevent-interface) handler via [`event.request`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#fetch-event-request).

You can poke at the `Request` in a variety of different ways, and one of those ways that might be sufficient to answer your question, though you won't be able to tell from the `Request` object exactly which `<img>` or `<script>` was responsible for triggering the `fetch` event.

- You can check `event.request.type`, which, as per the [specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-request-type), might be the empty string, or might have the values "audio", "font", "image", "script", "style", "track", or "video".
- You can of course check `event.request.url`, and attempt to infer from that whether it's a request for an image or a script or something else.
- You can look at the request's headers via `event.request.headers.get('x-header-name')` and check any of them that might be meaningful to you.
- You can check `event.request.mode`, which will be [set to different values](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode) depending on whether it's a navigation request, a request for a same-origin local resource, or a cross-origin request.

None of those will tell you directly whether a specific `<img>` tag was responsible for triggering a request, but it's not clear why knowing that specifically is necessary for your use case. (What is your use case, exactly?)

If you actually do need to know more information about which elements on your controlled pages made which requests, then perhaps including an additional URL query parameter when you populate your `src` attributes would be appropriate, and then you could check for those parameters via `event.request.url` inside your service worker.

Comment: My use case is kind of "if the request.type is image then cache it"